# too many values to unpack with quiver

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to use the quiver function to draw the vector field of a dynamic system.

I have 2 lists X and V.

I need to build 2 lists UE and VE containing respectively the first and second value returned by f, but I have the following error:

> too many values to unpack.

This is my code.

```
import numpy  as np
import scipy        # donne acces aux librairies scipy, scipy.linalg et scipy.integrate
import scipy.linalg
import scipy.integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
%matplotlib inline

def f(x,v,t):
    return v,-(float(g)/l)*np.sin(x)


t0=0
x0=1
v0=0
T=20
l=1
g=9.81
UE, VE = np.array([f(x,v,0) for x,v in zip(X,V)])
plt.quiver(X, Y, UE, VE)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't unpack a numpy array, try another approach to UE, VE = np.array([f(x,v,0) for x,v in zip(X,V)])

Comment: @GiovanniRescia: You can unpack a numpy array without any issues at all, as long as it contains the expected number of elements: `a, b = np.array([4, 6])` works. In this case, their array contains more than two elements though.

Comment: @Perelman: You haven't defined `X` or `V`, so running your code is impossible.

Comment: @fuglede Yes sorry, the code is extracted but you can take any array of integers using X=range(11, 17) and V=range(11, 19) for instance.

Comment: In that case, you may want to be aware that if you stick to NumPy arrays throughout, using e.g. `np.arange(11, 17)`, then you do not actually have to use `zip` to get to the values, as NumPy will internally (and in a vectorized, thus much more performant, fashion) take care of that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the details at the error, you should be able to find that the error in question occurs at

```
np.array([f(x,v,0) for x,v in zip(X,V)])
```

where the issue is that the array contains more than two elements, thus unpacking it into `UE` and `VE` is impossible.

In your case, it looks what you actually want is the transpose of the array,

```
np.array([f(x,v,0) for x,v in zip(X,V)]).T
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't know if I understand well your point about the transpose. What I want is to call f with an element of X and an element of V as arguments, and put the values returned by f into the lists UE and VE respectively

Comment: After transposing, the collection of the first return values for each input will be stored in `UE`, and the collection of second return values in `VE`; your array has shape `(?, 2)` when what you need is something of shape `(2, ?)`.